# Most rapidly differential question

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Two students memorize the name of drugs according to the following model

$dN/dt=2(1-N)$

a) Student A learn half of the names of drugs at time  $t=0$ and student B learn none. which student is learning most rapidly this instant?

b) Will student B catch up student A?

Here is what I got so far. For a), I find the function of $N$ and find that

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
N_A &=& 1-e^{2t}/2 \\
N_B &=& 1-e^{2t}
\end{eqnarray}
$$

For $N_A$ is number of name learns by stendent A and $N_B$ is number of names learn by student B. How can I continue from here?

Comment: Are you sure $N_A$ is correct? It looks like you used $N_A(0)=\frac{1}{2}$ rather than $N_A(0)=\frac{N}{2}$.

Comment: yes it's correct, since $N=1$ means that student know the entire names of drug, so if student A know only half of the name then $N_A=1/2$

Comment: oh ok. So the total number of drugs to be memorized is 1? I was just using N to represent the total number of drugs, whatever it may be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you need to solve the differential equation to answer the question.  For (a) the answer is student B because dN/dt=1 for student A and =2 for student B. For (b) the answer is that B can't catch up A because whatever the solution is, from a given starting point it evolves in the same way for both students B must always lag A.

Answer (score 2):

Take the derivative of both equations with respect to time, and whichever one has the greatest value at $t=0$ is learning most rapidly.

To determine whether or not B will catch up to A requires no derivatives. Just equate the two functions and solve for t. If there is no solution for t that is greater than 0, then B will not catch up to A.

Comment: Do you know how to do b), should I take second derivative?

Comment: @DianeVanderwaif see my latest edit